# ora-01017 invalid username/password logon denied can't logon with the new connection

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hey please am using oracle 11g XE and I have created a new user under the username "amine" and set the password to "amine" in SQL developer,
I have also granted all permissions and system privileges but when I try to create a new connection using the "amine" user it gives an ora-01017 even if the username and the password are correct
Steps that I tried :

-- setting the case sensitivity to FALSE

-- make sure that the user is created and the status is open (using sqlplus)

-- tried the command: alter user amine identified by "amine"; result ---> ORA-01918: user 'AMINE' does not exist

Comment: Have you granted authority to connect?  `grant create session to amine;` (You will also likely want to grant other privileges to allow querying existing tables, and to create new ones for that user.)

Comment: Please post the *exact* SQL commands used to create and provision your user.

Comment: @MarkStewart i created this user with sql developer and I granted all permissions and system privileges

Comment: @pmdba i used the sql developer tool to create it I didn't use sqlplus

Comment: Somewhere in SQL Developer I think there is an option to show what actual commands it uses for various GUI actions.  But just for fun, try the query `SELECT * FROM DBA_ROLE_PRIVS WHERE GRANTEE='AMINE";` and see.

Comment: @MarkStewart it gives me this error: ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "AMINE": invalid identifier

Comment: It sounds like the user isn't actually being created the way you think it is. Either that or you're connecting to the wrong database instance. The only way to confirm is to understand exactly what you did to create the user.

Comment: what i did is get connected using sys username and sysdba role all this using SQL developer and then I clicked on other users create new user fill in the user name and the password and switch te the roles tab clicked on grant all and same thing with the privileges tab and then clicked on apply and a success message shows up

Comment: I assume you fixed my syntax error in `GRANTEE='AMINE'` -- but... is the username in UPPERCASE or lower case?  Try `SELECT * FROM DBA_ROLE_PRIVS WHERE upper(GRANTEE)='AMINE';`

Comment: the problem is solved I just created the user using a script instead of using the SQL developer tool thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have created a new user under the username "amine"

It sounds like you have used the query:

```sql
CREATE USER "amine" IDENTIFIED BY "amine";
```

This will create a case-sensitive username and a case-sensitive password as you have surrounded the identifiers with double quotes.

If you try in SQL/Plus (or via equivalents in other UI such as SQL Developer's connection dialog) to use any one of these:

```
CONN amine/amine
CONN "amine"/amine
CONN amine/"amine"
```

Then it will fail as the unquoted values will be implicitly converted to upper-case as Oracle stores non-case-sensitive identifiers in upper-case.

You would always need to quote both the username and the password. I.e. in SQL/Plus

```
CONN "amine"/"amine"
```

Or using quotes in the username field in SQL Developer.

You can check if you did this by running:

```sql
SELECT username
FROM   all_users
WHERE  UPPER(username) = 'AMINE';
```

If the value comes back as lower-case (or, even, if there are now two users `amine` and `AMINE`) then you created the first one with a case-sensitive username and you will need to surround the username with double quotes whenever you want to use it.

Such as:

```sql
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO "amine";
```